# How to mock EntityBus.rxSend()

Tags: mockito, rx-java, rx-java2, vert.x, vertx-verticle

The `io.vertx.reactivex.core.eventbus.EventBus.rxSend()` method has the following signature:

```
public <T> Single<Message<T>> rxSend(String address,
                                     Object message,
                                     DeliveryOptions options)
```

What is the correct way to mock this so that it returns a `Single` containing a real object? The issue is that the `Message` class has no constructor apart from one which which takes another `Message` object.
So the following will compile:

```
Mockito.when(eventBus.rxSend(Mockito.isA(String.class), 
   Mockito.isA(JsonObject.class), 
   Mockito.isA(DeliveryOptions.class))).thenReturn(Single.just(new Message<Object>(null)));
```

but of course `Single.just(new Message<Object>(null))`does not contain a real object which can then be passed on to test the next handler in the verticle.

Thanks

Comment: not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered simply using real instances over mocks? i found this to be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yes, one can do that using Mockito.spy(). The issue however with using the real EventBus is that it will send the message to an endpoint address which won't have been setup within the context of a unit test.

Comment: no, I mean create a fake listener that gives back canned replies based on the sent data on the other end of that address. you don't need to mock anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like i mentioned in my comment, i don't have an answer to your immediate question, but i'd instead like to recommend a different approach to getting the results you're looking for.

mocking types that you don't own is generally discouraged for a variety of reasons. the two that resonate most with me (as i've fallen victim) are:

- if the real implementation of the mocked dependency changes, the mock's behavior will not automatically reveal any forward-breaking changes.
- the more mocks a test introduces, the more cognitive load the test carries. and some tests require a lot of mocks in order to work.

there are lots of articles on the topic with more detailed viewpoints and opinions. if you're interested, refer to the [Mockito wiki](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own), or just Google around.

given all that, rather than mocking `EventBus`, why not use an actual instance and receive real reply `Messages` composed by the framework? sure, strictly speaking this becomes more of an integration test than a unit test, but is closer to the type of testing you want.

here's an example snippet from a test i wrote in an existing project with some added comments. (the code refers to some non-standard types with an -"Ext" suffix, but they aren't salient to the approach).

```
private EventBus eventBus;

@Before
public setUp(@NotNull TestContext context) {
    eventBus = Vertx.vertx().eventBus()
}

@Test
public void ping_pong_reply_test(@NotNull TestContext context) {
    final Async async = context.async();

    // the following is a MessageConsumer registered 
    // with the EventBus for this specific test. 
    // the reference is retained so that it can be 
    // "unregistered()" upon completion of this test
    // so as not to affect other tests. 

    final MessageConsumer<JsonObject> consumer = eventBus.consumer(Ping.class.getName(), message -> {
        // here is where you would otherwise place
        // your mock Message generation.

        MessageExt.replyAsJsonObject(message, new Pong());
    });

    final Ping message = new Ping();
    final DeliveryOptions options = null;

    // the following uses an un-mocked EventBus to 
    // send an event and receive a real Message reply.
    // created by the consumer above.

    EventBusExt.rxSendJsonObject(eventBus, message, options).subscribe(
            result -> 
                // result.body() is JSON that conforms to 
                // the Pong type

                consumer.unregister();

                async.complete();
            },
            error -> {
                context.fail(error);
            }
    );
}
```

i hope this at least inspires some new thinking around your problem.