# Vertx: how to create Message for unit-testing?

Tags: message, vert.x, creation

I need to create a Message for unit-testing. How to create Message in Vertx?

Answer (score 2):

You can mock the `Message` with your favorite mocking library. But in general, Vert.x users simply start a Vert.x instance for testing, since it's small and embeddable. Then you no longer mock but register test consumers and publishers.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to use the real classes. i recently wrote a detailed answer advocating the approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150250/how-to-mock-entitybus-rxsend/52158658#52158658